How Linux processes and modules choose numa node
I have a Ubuntu 22.04 server which is numa enabled node with 4 nodes. Comparatively other nodes, memory usage is high on node0. I noticed this contains most of the system binaries, services and associated libraries.
My question is how these chosen node0 to run on it even there is no explicit numa polices configured. Thanks in advance.

When the system is not under a concerning amount of memory pressure, a node having more utilization is not by itself actionable. Tasks try to stick to their nodes: local memory is faster, and interconnects are bottlenecks.
Bad analogy: imagine a library system, with many far-flung physical locations. Hosted at one of these branches is a newspaper archive. Visiting patrons would find it convenient if the entirety of a collection was in one place. Inter library transport or visiting another location might take hours or days. Analogous to a slow interconnect.
Linux memory and scheduling systems are aware of NUMA nodes. Evenly allocated is not the priority, maximizing locality is. Likely your system happened to boot from that node, and various tasks started whose memory allocations were satisfied with local memory.   From the pretty good introduction in the kernel docs, What is NUMA?

Local allocation will tend to keep subsequent access to the allocated
memory “local” to the underlying physical resources and off the system
interconnect– as long as the task on whose behalf the kernel allocated
some memory does not later migrate away from that memory. The Linux
scheduler is aware of the NUMA topology of the platform–embodied in
the “scheduling domains” data structures [see Scheduler Domains]–and
the scheduler attempts to minimize task migration to distant
scheduling domains. However, the scheduler does not take a task’s NUMA
footprint into account directly. Thus, under sufficient imbalance,
tasks can migrate between nodes, remote from their initial node and
kernel data structures.
System administrators and application designers can restrict a task’s
migration to improve NUMA locality using various CPU affinity command
line interfaces, such as taskset(1) and numactl(1), and program
interfaces such as sched_setaffinity(2). Further, one can modify the
kernel’s default local allocation behavior using Linux NUMA memory
policy. [see NUMA Memory Policy].

Despite these tools existing, many Linux workloads on multi node systems do not need to be micromanaged by a person.
Some capacity planning helps.
Does every workload on this host fit in one node? Database, VM guest, container. If they do fit, that's the easy case. Remote memory references will be rare, minimizing those difficult to diagnose problems where some memory accesses are slower.
Spanning nodes is possible, as in a very large VM guest or database shared memory segment. But might call for more sophisticated software and operations to extract the maximum performance.
And the overall system memory capacity is a consideration, same as one node systems. MemAvailable from /proc/meminfo should remain a comfortable percentage of MemTotal.

Hi John, Thanks for looking into it. The server accommodates more of qemu VM's. VM's memory is spread across all 4 numa nodes with 'default'. Some maps on n1, some are on n2, some are on n3 and some are on mixed nodes except below one which policy is bind:3 in this case. AFAIK, 'bind' sticks to one node which is 3, but below 'bind' map spread over 3 nodes. I assume this is remote-node and impacts latency.  My question is how it chosen  the Numa nodes.
7f3c5fe00000   bind:3   anon=226122   dirty=226122   mapmax=256   active=118316   N0=538   N1=188   N3=225396 kernelpagesize_kB=4
